# which preposition should I use with "elaborate"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, word-usage

I have the following sentence, and I am wondering which preposition(s) should I use to make this sentence grammatically correct.

> This will be elaborated on in the following section.

There are two more variations of usages of `on in` as follows:

> This will be elaborated on the following section.

and

> This will be elaborated in the following section.

I obviously can see many examples as `in the following section`, but still I also can see some of `on in the following section` usage.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Merelyto avoid a weak-sounding juxtaposition, I'd use 'This will be elaborated upon in the following section.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for your comment. Would you write this as an answer so that I can accept this as the answer for this?

Comment: I'm sorry; I don't think the question is suitable for ELU. You might find our sister site, ELL, more suitable. // 'Elaborate on + noun phrase' means 'discuss more fully'; though 'elaborate' can be used with a direct object, it is non-standard here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth OK, actually I thought I posted this on ELL instead here at first. But it was not. Thanks for what you elaborated on the usage of "elaborate", it really helped me a lot.

Comment: I will elaborate on this question in the next section.  I will write about this question in the next section.  I will consider this question in the next section.  So "in the next section" is just an adverbial, nothing special to do with the verb "elaborate".